# Windows Form and Socket Class Co-Usage

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, static

I've come into an issue that must be quite common, but with little insight around the world of Google.

You see, my project has 3 parts that I use:

- CommunicationClass.cs (Asynchronous Socket Class)
- Form1.Designer.cs (Containing the objects of Form1)
- Form1.cs (Main constructor and contains event handlers for objects)

Pretty basic setup.

However, I don't know where I put my communication class instance. The communication class sends/receives messages. So, my instance of ComClass in Form1 would use its void Send() in the event handler for the enter key being pressed (while in a textBox).

That works fine. What doesn't work fine is when the ComClass RECEIVES a message. It can't use the non-static voids of PrintMessage() in Form1.cs, and PrintMessage can't be a static void because richTextBox1, where the messages are shown, is non-static.

I'm wondering if another component of C# will help me access these and overcome my problem, but I'm too new to C# to know. I want to keep using the layout I have rather than switch to one like an example TCP chat client, where the form is created outside of Program.cs.

Comment: Why can't non-static members be used? If you have threading issues, consider either using Form.Invoke to execute a method on the GUI thread, or place your messages on a Queue which is polled by a timer on your form (scales better but more complicated)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear about the issue. When I reference a non-static void it says: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Project.Form1.PrintMessage()'".

I never said I had threading issues (explicitly), but I would be entirely open to using threading if this would solve my problem.

Comment: Threading and inter-class communications are two orthogonal issues. There's nothing in your original question that could be addressed simply by saying "put it in a thread". :) (Which is not to say that you won't wind up finding some thread/concurrency-related approach useful here...just that doing so solves different problems than the one you asked about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the standard paradigm for stuff like this is to use events. This ties in with the idea of the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in software design.

You are already using that for handling the key-press. The "trick" is to implement an event on your CommClass that the Form instance can subscribe to, in order to receive notification of incoming data.

The usual .NET Forms implementation is usually a kind of "poor man's MVC", in which the Form class winds up acting as controller and view all at the same time. Of course, doing so negates the main benefit of an MVC design, which is that the view is completely independent of the controller.

But you could (after learning more about the MVC design pattern) create a third "controller" class that ties together the view (your Form) and the model (your CommClass where the actual meat of the work is implemented).

If you want to go really cheesy, you could just pass your Form instance directly to the CommClass and have some special method that the CommClass knows to call when it receives data. But that's just doubling-down on the failure to separate concerns between your class, tying them even more closely. Maybe okay for a quick-and-dirty proof of concept, but that's no way to write code that you have any interest in reusing some time in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I just remembered that C# had events.. In AS3 it was really easy for me to write simple scripts using `object.addEventListener();`. It was also really easy to write `parent.addEventListener();`

As for the MVC comment, a concept I'm _somewhat_ familiar with, I'm not totally sure that you could do that, in this instance. Program.cs would be the parent of Form1 so trying to create a controller for Form1 would involve some complex rethinking. Unless I'm dead wrong. Either way, thanks!

Comment: You can implement MVC just fine. You could even make the Program class your controller if you wanted to go that route. Alternatively, you could leave Program as it is and let the Form instance create an instance of a different controller class when it is created (don't get too hung up thinking that just because some section of code created something, that it now _owns_ that something :) ).